# setbackground is not working for cell

Tags: java, itext

I am trying to set the background color for a particular section in the row.

```
Cell myCell = new PCell(tablename);
myCell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
myCell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_TOP);
if(mycondition) {
  myCell.setFixedHeight(2f);
  myCell.setBackgroundColor(colorFourteenDay);
}
mytable.addCell(myCell);
```

but the `setBackgroundColor` is applying color for the whole row, so can you help me how to set the color for a particular section of row.

`myCell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);`...... and after using this code section also the border is coming

Comment: What package does this `PCell` class come from?

Comment: this is my own custom package

Comment: Which version of iText are you using, and what does the `PCell` class look like? Maybe the problem is in your own class, not in iText.

Comment: We'll need the code of `PCell` (at least the relevant bits) if you want any help